# Proving the inequality $\ln(\cos x)\ge \frac{-x^2}{\cos^2(x)}$ for $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: inequality

I want to prove the following inequality: $\ln(\cos x)\ge \dfrac{-x^2}{\cos^2(x)}$

Please I'm stuck with this problem, maybe considering the equivalent inequality $\ln(\sec x)\ge (x \sec x)^2$ would help, but I'm not sure.
I want to prove it by the use of the Mean Value theorem.

Comment: The equivalent inequality is $\ln(\sec x)\le (x \sec x)^2$

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f(x) = x^2 + \cos^2(x) \ln(\cos(x))$. Show that $f(x)$ is increasing for $x \in [0,\pi/2)$ and conclude what you want.

Comment: The [derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+x%5E2%2B%28cos%28x%29%29%5E2%28log%28cos%28x%29%29) looks untreatable. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: @GitGud It is actually pretty easy to show that the [derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%28x%5E2+%2B+%5Ccos%5E2%28x%29+%5Cln%28%5Ccos%28x%29%29%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2) is positive. Use the fact that $-\sin(x)\cos(x) \log(\cos(x))$ is always positive and $2x - \sin(x) \cos(x) = 2x - \dfrac{\sin(2x)}2 > 0$.

Comment: @Inceptio What? Can't you differentiate $\log(\cos(x))$ and $\cos^2(x)$? You do not need wolfram for this. You often seem to leave comments without thinking.

Comment: But my teacher wants a proof by the use of the mean value theorem )=

Comment: @user17762: Sorry, deleted my comment after seeing your edited comment. I agree with you(first part only).

Answer (score 0):

$$
\ln (1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}3 - \cdots.
$$
$$
\ln\cos x = \ln\left(1 -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}-\cdots\right) \ge\ln\left(1 -\frac{x^2}{2}\right)
$$
$$
=\frac{-x^2}{2} -\frac{x^4}{8} + \cdots \ge -\frac{x^2}{1.5} \ge-\frac{x^2}{\cos^2 x}\text{ for $x$ close enough to $0$.}
$$